# azure application insights to track standalone java program

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am currently using azure application isights for web apps. 
Can it be used to gather metrics from a standalone java program? I am not finding a good documentation related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the telemetry:
TelemetryConfiguration.getActive().setInstrumentationKey("your_key");

Post custom events:
    TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
    tc.trackRequest(new  RequestTelemetry("custom event request",new Date(),1000,"200", true));
    tc.trackEvent("custom event");
    tc.flush();

Comment: What is wrong with [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics)?